# Swift UIFont IBInspectable - is it possible?

Tags: swift, uiview, attributes, interface-builder, uifont

I have a `UIView` subclass. In this view I create instances of `UIlabel`. 
Now I want to set the font attributes for these labels in the Storyboard. Is it possible to make an `IBInspectable` for `UIFont`?

One of my approaches was this:

`@IBInspectable var fontName: UIFont`

But it won't work.

To wrap it up: I trying to get this for the `UIView`:

[image: Font IBInspectable]

I hope someone can help me, thank you! :)

Comment: What a shame that this is not possible without hacking. Apple should add this in Xcode 9.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Idea

You can use Int enums to select one of the certain fonts.

### Details

xCode 8.2.1, Swift 3

### Code

> enum FontType: Int

```
import UIKit
enum FontType: Int {
    case Default = 0, Small, Large

    var fount: UIFont {
        switch self {
            case .Default:
                return UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
            case .Small:
                return UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
            case .Large:
                return UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24)
        }
    }


    static func getFont(rawValue: Int) -> UIFont  {
        if let fontType = FontType(rawValue: rawValue) {
            return fontType.fount
        }
        return FontType.Default.fount
    }
}
```

> class View: UIView

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class View: UIView {

    private var label: UILabel!

    @IBInspectable var textFont:Int = 0

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 120, height: 40))
        label.text = "Text"
        label.textColor = .black
        label.font = FontType.getFont(rawValue: textFont)
        addSubview(label)
    }

}
```

> Main.storyboard

[image]

### Results

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I have done this way

```
fileprivate var _fontSize:CGFloat = 18
    @IBInspectable
    var font:CGFloat
    {
        set
        {
            _fontSize = newValue
            lblPlaceholder.font = UIFont(name: _fontName, size: _fontSize)
        }
        get
        {
            return _fontSize
        }
    }

    fileprivate var _fontName:String = "Helvetica"
    @IBInspectable
    var fontName:String
    {
        set
        {
            _fontName = newValue
            lblPlaceholder.font = UIFont(name: _fontName, size: _fontSize)
        }
        get
        {
            return _fontName
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @IBInspectable var isShowfontName : Bool  = false
    @IBInspectable var fontFamilyIndex : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: -1, y: -1 )
    var  leoFontName : String? {

        if Int(fontFamilyIndex.x) >= 0 && Int(fontFamilyIndex.x) < UIFont.familyNames.sorted().count {

            let fontNames = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: UIFont.familyNames.sorted()[Int(fontFamilyIndex.x)])

            if Int(fontFamilyIndex.y) >= 0 && Int(fontFamilyIndex.y) < fontNames.count {

                return  fontNames[Int(fontFamilyIndex.y)]
            }


            return fontNames.first ?? nil

        }



        return nil
    }
```