# How to use UIFontMetrics in storyboard in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, textstyle

I am Kickbell.

I'm trying to improve accessibility in my app.
So, I am solving the problem by referring to the official documentation below.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically

But I have a question.

Since I programing with a storyboard, the code below is not the way I want it to be.

```swift
let font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 18.0)!
label.font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body).scaledFont(for: customFont)
```

Is there a way to use @IBInspectable and @IBDesignable ?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift UIFont IBInspectable - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089274/swift-uifont-ibinspectable-is-it-possible)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But unfortunately it's not the answer I'm looking for. Thank you.